# How give aws credential to jenkins pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have following configuration in my jenkins pipeline

```
s3Upload( file:'ok.txt', bucket:'my-buckeck', path:'file.txt')
```

Problem is s3Upload function is not taking AWS access keys that i have stored in jenkins

i tied with following code

```
    withAWS(profile:'Test Publisher') {
    s3Upload( file:'ok.txt', bucket:'my-buckeck', path:'file.txt')

}
```

[image: s3 profile]

my s3 profile in jenkins is like that. still am getting profile file could not find error. How can i upload file from jenkins to s3 using s3Upload function ?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I literally cannot get this to work

Answer (score 10):

To be able to upload to S3, you need to save your credentials in environment variables on your Jenkins:

`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<region of bucket>`

`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<aws id>`

`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<your s3 access key>`

To do that, just go to Jenkins - Manage Jenkins - Configure System - Global properties - Environment variables

Answer (score 4):

I think you may have confused the S3 Publisher plugin with the AWS plugin.

That screenshot is from the S3 Publisher plugin, https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/S3+Plugin.  There is a warning not to update to latest version. Looks like compatibility for pipeline is broken, there is this warning "Version 0.10.11 (Dec 31, 2016) - do not update - backward compatibility for pipeline scripts are broken".

However, it looks like your pipeline code is for the Jenkins AWS plugin. https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin. To use credentials with that plugin you must do one of the following:

1. store access key, secret key in Jenkins credential store.
2. read from Jenkins' AWS config file.

These options are documented in the plugin README https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin

```
Use Jenkins UsernamePassword credentials information (Username: AccessKeyId, Password: SecretAccessKey):    
withAWS(credentials:'nameOfSystemCredentials') {
    // do something
}

Use profile information from ~/.aws/config:
withAWS(profile:'myProfile') {
    // do something
}
```

"profile" is the profile section of your AWS config file. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html

Then you can use the S3 upload feature. https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin#s3upload

Comment: I'm using the `withAWS` step and have AWS credentials with name `accesskey` and ID `jenkins`. When I call it as `withAWS(credentials:'jenkins')` or as `withAWS(credentials:'accesskey')` I keep hitting this exception. The credentials look good per my Jenkins mgmt console (there's a log saying last used successfully with a recent time). What could I be missing?

Comment: @scorpiodawg your question sounds a bit different than the original. Could you start a new question with as much info as possible?

Comment: I asked this here: https://serverfault.com/questions/958350/jenkins-global-aws-credentials-not-working-via-withaws-step @mike-marseglia