# Jenkins global AWS credentials not working via `withAWS` step

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jenkins

I have a Jenkins v2.62 instance with the pipeline plugin installed and successfully  usable. I have AWS credentials that are tested and working:

[image: AWS creds]

Now my pipeline job has something like this:

```
node("deploy-staging") {
    stage('test') {
        withEnv(["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}",
                 "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}",
                 "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}"]) {
            // WORKS
            s3put -b my-bucket -k foo -p `pwd` text.txt
        }

        withAWS(credentials:'jenkins') {
            // DOES NOT WORK!
            s3Upload bucket: "my-bucket", path: "foo/text.txt"
        }

        echo "Done."
    }
}
```

I verified that the `withEnv` block works (because the Jenkins instance is configured with those three env variables globally set), but the `withAWS` block does *not* for some reason that I'm unable to figure out. I checked that there are no spaces in the name `jenkins`. The job hits this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find Jenkins credentials with name jenkins
    at de.taimos.pipeline.aws.WithAWSStep$Execution.withCredentials(WithAWSStep.java:179)
    at de.taimos.pipeline.aws.WithAWSStep$Execution.start(WithAWSStep.java:151)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:184)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod$47.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:26)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor402.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:230)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

The `withAWS` step appears to come from plugin of which I have version `1.7` installed.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates the credentials named "jenkins" do not exist:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find Jenkins credentials with name jenkins
```

The pipeline step that uses the "jenkins" credentials is:

```
withAWS(credentials:'jenkins') {
            // DOES NOT WORK!
            s3Upload bucket: "my-bucket", path: "foo/text.txt"
        }
```

According to the documentation for the "withAWS" pipeline step, https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-aws/#withaws-set-aws-settings-for-nested-block, the credentials should be a type of "Username/Password" credentials.

```
credentials (optional)
     Use standard Jenkins UsernamePassword credentials. Note: the username
should be your Access Key ID, and the password should be the Secret Access Key.
```

The credentials screenshot shows an "AWS" credentials type with "Access Key ID" and "Secret Access Key" fields.

Create a new credential type of "Username/Password" and use it with the `withAWS` pipeline step.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are writing your credentials in a different way than I. This way it should work for you.

```
withAWS(region: 'us-east-2', credentials: 'Nour') {
          s3Upload(file: 'generate.html', bucket: 'nouran.portfolio', path: 'generate.html')
}
```